# ruby project firebase hosting css not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase

[website running perfectly on localhost but not when hosted to firebase.css part is not showing .already put all my files to public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhRWz.jpg)

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there will drastically increase the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.